# Filtering df column from (19:01, the last day before the max day in the table) to (max day in the table, 5:59)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a column and pandas dataframe called **final_report['TemporaryDateFilter']**

This contains all sorts of dates and its updated every day

The dates are in this format:

| TemporaryDateFilter |
| --- |
| 2022-12-15 00:26:14 |
| 2023-01-27 04:38:22 |
| 2023-01-27 18:22:39 |
| 2023-01-26 16:33:15 |
| 2023-01-27 08:50:12 |
| 2023-01-26 23:23:15 |

What I need is to:

1, I need to filter it by time and day, as follows: **from date before latest date 20:01 to latest date 5:59**

(So in this case it would be from 2023-01-26 20:01 to 2023-01-27 05:59)

**I don't know which date is the latest so the script has to find it.**

pd.DateOffset doesn't work for some reason.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is that date stored as a string or as datetime object of some kind.. you may need to convert it to a datetime or pandas datatime object

Answer (score 0):

in case the date is stored as a string
convert it to datetime format using

```
#convert date to datetime if it is a string
df.final_report['TemporaryDateFilter']=pd.to_datetime(df["TemporaryDateFilter"])
```

if already in datetime format skip above

```
df.sort_values(by=['TemporaryDateFilter'])

last_date=df["TemporaryDateFilter"][-1]
lastdate=lastdate.replace(hour=5, minute=59)

tempdf=df.loc[ df["TemporaryDateFilter"]<last_date.replace(hour=0,minute=0) ]
prev_date=tempdf["TemporaryDateFilter"][-1]
prev_date=prev_date.replace(hour=20,minute=1)

filtered_df=df.loc[df["TemporaryDateFilter"]>=prev_date && df["TemporaryDateFilter"]<=last_date]
```